# Retrofit2: ExecutorCallAdapterFactory error

Tags: android, retrofit2

After calling API's using Retrofit 2.0, Unable to get any response and getting this error:

**Failure: retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@5e38d31**

I think this is internal retrofit error.
Please help!

Comment: Me too getting the same...didn't get any tweak yet.

Comment: @Sunny can you post your code?

Comment: @Mohammad Sunny you must post your case

Comment: I`m also getting the same error and stuck in this error 2 to 3 days my project is in development process please help me.

Comment: Hi Asad, I have post an answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was using different wifi server and the server on which API is deployed.Then I use same server for both and my issue was resolved.